# error when directing to protected page after login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

SO i made a website with a login feature. You can only access the website after you register and login. Registration works and the session is started when the login button is pressed but i get error's when being redirected to the protected page.
I get following error's:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webdata/domains/cim-gmbh.ch/vhosts/www/htdocs/login.php:7) in /webdata/domains/cim-gmbh.ch/vhosts/www/htdocs/login.php on line 40
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webdata/domains/cim-gmbh.ch/vhosts/www/htdocs/login.php:7) in /webdata/domains/cim-gmbh.ch/vhosts/www/htdocs/login.php on line 44

and here is the entire login.php file:

```
 <?php

include "mysql_connectinfo.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['angemeldet']) || $_SESSION['angemeldet']) {
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT $mysqlname FROM $mysqltable WHERE $mysqlname='$username'AND $mysqlpwd='$passwort'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($num != 0) {
  $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

  if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
    if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
      header('Status: 303 See Other');
    }
    else {
      header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other'); //this is line 40
    }
  }

  header('Location: index.php'); //this is line 44
  exit;
}
else {
  echo mysql_error();
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: The session is started, because i can access the protected pages which would redirect me to login.php if i wasn't logged in.

Comment: feel free to try it out yourself.
www.cim-gmbh.ch

Comment: ok, it's not the byte order mark! Opened it in dreamweaver and it wasn't enabled. It keeps giving me the error in these two headers:

    `if ($num != 0) {
      $_SESSION['angemeldet'] = true;

      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] == 'HTTP/1.1') {
        if (php_sapi_name() == 'cgi') {
         header('Status: 303 See Other');
        }
        else {
          header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
       }
      }

      header('Location: index.php');
      exit;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: I actually found a solution. I rewrote the php script by following a tutorial on phpacademy.org! I then changed the auth.php which protects the pages to fit the process.php which goes through the login procedure. It's alot simpler than i expected but thank you for your help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no space/indentation before first openeng tag `<?php` you have:

```
 <?php

include "mysql_connectinfo.php";
```

Also make sure you don't echo/output anything in `mysql_connectinfo.php` file.

Since you are using `$_SESSION`, you also need to make sure that you have `session_start()` at start of your script:

```
<?php
session_start();
// more code
```

Comment: `mysql_connectinfo.php` is used for the connection to the mysql db/tables and contains the error messages when it cannot connect!

Comment: @NickMüller: That could be the potential problem. Since it will output error, header error can be caused by that. Also check for other reasons i have mentioned.

Comment: ok so i removed the error messages from `mysql_connectinfo.php` but i still get the above errors.

Comment: @NickMüller: Make sure there is no space/indentation before `<?php` and after `?>` in your current file as well as mysql_connectinfo.php

Comment: There are no spaces what soever. I always try to not make those simple mistakes. but i double checked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code editor doesn't include a BOM in the document. I know for a fact that notepad++ and some others include this by default. If it is included, it will insert invisible characters into your document, which looks like output to the server, causing the error messages you're seeing. Try copying and pasting your code into a NEW document that does not have the BOM.

I had this same problem a couple weeks ago, and creating a new php document in Dreamweaver WITHOUT the BOM (byte order mark) solved the issue.

Comment: I am using notepad++ and in different forums the problem was brought up. What editor should i use? I am seriously sick of this problem!

Comment: Still doesn't work. Copied and pasted the entire login.php into a new document not using notepad++ but the normal notepad.

Comment: You have to designate somewhere in your preferences to NOT use the BOM. I myself use Dreamweaver, but I'm sure there are other options out there. To remove the BOM: You can just open the file in Notepad++ and check Format → UTF-8 without BOM. Alternatively, you can open the file in a hex editor and remove the “EF BB boyfriend” from the beginning of the document.